# How to make a responsiveness 2/3 row

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, grid, responsive

As far as understanding mobile first responsiveness from [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/), in this section [W3.CSS Built-In Responsiveness](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_responsive.asp) ➡ ["The w3-twothird Class"](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_responsive_twothird&stacked=h), I am just having a hard time understanding what the CSS styling is for these two rows for both **w3-twothird** and **w3-third**. I get it that one is for 66% of its width and the other is for the 33% width, both in the same row.

What I'm not getting is how do I edit it into my own styling sheet to find the width that I want in whatever row I desire. Or just in general just how to even place them into my webpage in the first place.

Right now it looks kind of awkward as shown below, but what is the CSS so that I can style it myself. Which is the question that I'm asking. It just gives out a link to an already pre-made styling sheet and looks kind of messy so I am at lost here.

```css
.w3-twothird {
  width: 66%;
  background: red;
}

.w3-third {
  width: 33%;
  background: cyan;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .w3-twothird .w3-third {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

/* In my mind this is what I'm thinking but the tutorial doesn't show us how to do it! This is so confusing and I have no idea where to begin! */
```

```html
<div class="w3-row w3-border">
  <div class="w3-twothird w3-container w3-red">
    <h2>w3-twothird</h2>
    <p>The w3-twothird class uses 66% of the parent container.</p>
    <p>On screens smaller than 601 pixels it resizes to full screen.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-third w3-container">
    <h2>w3-third</h2>
    <p>The w3-twothird class uses 33% of parent container.</p>
    <p>On screens smaller than 601 pixels it resizes to full screen.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<br>

<div class="w3-row w3-border">
  <div class="w3-third w3-container">
    <h2>w3-third</h2>
    <p>The w3-twothird class uses 33% of parent container.</p>
    <p>On screens smaller than 601 pixels it resizes to full screen.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-twothird w3-container w3-red">
    <h2>w3-twothird</h2>
    <p>The w3-twothird class uses 66% of the parent container.</p>
    <p>On screens smaller than 601 pixels it resizes to full screen.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure I understand your question.

In the head of your doc you need to include a viewport meta tag and you also need to import the w3.css file, or download a copy and upload it to your site. This CSS file includes styling for the w3-twothird and w3-third columns, and lots else as well. See https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/default.asp for more details.

The whole idea with frameworks like w3.css, Bootstrap, and all the others, is that they provide you with basic styling for your grid, so you can quickly code your rows and columns. You don't need to try and build the CSS for the column widths yourself, just focus on setting the correct classes and w3.css will calculate the widths for you.

So your final HTML would be
https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/wvBdGJq

```
<html>
<title>Page title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- import w3.css from w3schools, or better still, download a copy and host it on your own site -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<body>

  <div class="w3-third w3-container">
      <h2>w3-third</h2>
      <p>The w3-twothird class uses 33% of parent container.</p>
      <p>On screens smaller than 601 pixels it resizes to full screen.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-twothird w3-container w3-red">
    <h2>w3-twothird</h2>
    <p>The w3-twothird class uses 66% of the parent container.</p>
    <p>On screens smaller than 601 pixels it resizes to full screen.</p>
  </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Good luck, I hope this helps you get unstuck!